# C++: matching pipe-delimited strings with wildcards using boost::regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost

Suppose I would like to match for the following pipe-delimited strings:

```
std::string re("a|*|c");
std::string x("a|b|c");
std::string y("a|c|d");

does_match( re, x );  // want to return TRUE
does_match( re, y );  // want to return FALSE
```

what is the best way to implement `does_match()` using boost::regex?

I think I may be running into issues with escaping pipes and stars.  Note that I don't care about the actual matches: I just want an easy-to-use interface to `does_match()` to tell me if I have a match.

In particular, I hope to get this working without having to use a ton of escapes for pipes and stars.  I don't care about other more general uses of regex - if I can use pipe-delimiters and * for wildcards, that's sufficient.

Maybe I should do a transform inside does_match to make boost::regex happy?  Or perhaps my entire approach is bad (like I should be using some kind of strsplit() instead?).

Comment: Well, `|` *is* a special character in any form of regex language, so you won't get around escaping it... mind you, C++ string literals also need to escape backslashes, so it'll be something like `"a\\\|*\\\|c"`. Hoping to do without is like "I was hoping to write some C++ without all those curly braces and classes".

Comment: @KerrekSB: One extra \ is enough, and the star can't be alone (it's a modifier). So the C++ string of the regex would be `"a\\|.*\\|c"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I'm barking up the wrong tree by attempting to solve this with boost::regex() - boost::split() is probably more appropriate.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

bool does_match( const std::string& fmt, const std::string& str )
{
    std::vector<std::string> strs, fmts;
    boost::split( strs, str, boost::is_any_of( "|" ));
    boost::split( fmts, fmt, boost::is_any_of( "|" ));
    if ( strs.size()!=fmts.size() )
        return false;
    size_t n = strs.size(); 
    for( size_t i=0; i<n; ++i )
        if ( fmts[i].compare("*")  && fmts[i].compare( strs[i] ))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your regex has to be like this `a\\|.*?\\|c` in order to match what you want. `|` has special meaning (logical or). And `*` has a special meaning (zero or more times). If the middle part is mandatory then use `a\\|.+?\\|c`.

Answer (score 1):

The default pattern for what you're trying to do would require
`"a\\|.*\\|c"`.  If your compiler supports C++11, you could use a raw
string to specify this: `R"(a\|.*\|c)".  Otherwise, you can use a syntax
in which`|`was not a meta-character; Boost supports the Posix basic
syntax, for example, which doesn't support the or-operator, so you could
write`"a|.*|c"`:

```
boost::regex pattern("a|.*|c", boost::regex::basic);
```

(You could use `sed` or `grep` instead of `basic`.)